# Trying to extract 'text' from a tag using Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to extract the Proxy IP number on the first column in this page (https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-fr/), just the number for example: "178.33.62.155" but when I try to extract all the text content on the relevant tag , it doesn't get the Ip text.

The html tag on the website is:

`<td align="left"><script>document.write('23178.3'.substr(2) + '3.62.155');</script>178.33.62.155</td>`

Then I believe the Ip number above (after the tag script, inside the tag ) should appears when I print the text content, but it doesn't, following the code below I have done so far the only information that doesn't appears is the IP number.

Any idea on how to extract this specific Ip information and why it is not appearing when I extract all the text content of this tag?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import re

page = requests.get('https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-fr/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content.decode('utf-8'))

for elem in tree.xpath('//table[@class="table"]//tbody//td[@align="left"]'):
print elem.text_content()
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the tags in your loop, to make sure it's getting the right ones?

Comment: You mention a URL with `country-fr` in your question text but a URL with `country-br` in your code. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @BillBell No it doesn't make difference sorry, fr means Ips from France and br means Ips from brazil. I have fixed my comments.

Comment: @JohnGordon - Yes I did, it always returning the text: "document.write('23178.3'.substr(2) + '3.62.155');", but not "178.33.62.155".

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that `178.33.62.155` is not itself an element; it is the text content of the `<td>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4). like this.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-fr/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")

REGEX_JS = re.compile("^document\.write\('([^']+)'\.substr\(2\) \+ '([^']+)'\);$")

proxy_ip_list = []
for table in soup.find_all("table", id="tbl_proxy_list"):
    for script in table.find_all("script"):
        m = REGEX_JS.search(script.text)
        if m:
            proxy_ip_list.append(m.group(1)[2:] + m.group(2))

for ip in proxy_ip_list:
    print(ip)
```

Comment: Your answer helped me get my answer.

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was trying to do. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I admit that I wouldn't have got this without tell's answer because I missed how the IP addresses were coded in the scripts.

```
import re
import requests
from lxml import etree

page = requests.get('https://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-fr/').text
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(page, parser=parser)
table = tree.xpath('.//table[@id="tbl_proxy_list"]//script/text()')

for item in table:
    m = re.match(r"document.write\('23([0-9.]+)'[^']+'([0-9.]+)'",item)
    if m:
        print (''.join(m.groups()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it also helped me to understand how to do it using a different approach.